# C++ call templated constructor for template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class, with variadic argument list:

```
template<class ...Args>
struct Data{
};
```

Now I want to have constructor with variadic "universal reference" argument list, so I make my constructor templated:

```
template<class ...Args>
struct Data{

    template<class ...CtrArgs>
    Data(CtrArgs&& ... args){
        // do something
    }

};
```

And now I want to make an instance of `Data`:

```
Data<int, MyClass, bool> dat(1, MyClass(), false);
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     Is this Args? Or CtrArgs?
```

The question is, does this `<int, MyClass, bool>` goes to Args, or to CtrArgs?

P.S. Maybe this is easy to check. But I ask this because I have very strange behavior in more complex case.

Comment: `Data<int, MyClass, bool>` is `Args`. `CtrArgs` is then deduced from the constructor parameters as `int, MyClass, bool`.

Comment: There is no way to explicitly specify template arguments to the constructor. The `CtrArgs` can only be deduced from the arguments given to the constructor.

Comment: @T.C. not as `int&&, MyClass&&, bool&&` ?

Comment: @tower120 No, the `&&` is added in your function argument list. The deduced types themselves are reference-less.

Comment: @T.C. Oh I see, thank you. They are always reference-less? That deduced ones?

Comment: @tower120 If you pass an rvalue. If you pass an lvalue the type will be deduced as `T&`, i.e., an lvalue reference, then reference collapsing turns `T& &&` into `T&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data<int, MyClass, bool>` is the type obtained by instantiating the class template `Data` with the template arguments `int`, `MyClass`, `bool`. So in your example, the template arguments go to `Args`.

There is no way to explicitly specify template arguments for a constructor. The C++ standard even says so unequivocally (§14.8.1/7):

> [ *Note:* Because the explicit template argument list follows the function template name, and because conversion member function templates and constructor member function templates are called without using a
>   function name, there is no way to provide an explicit template argument list for these function templates.
>   — *end note* ]

Comment: I want `CtrArgs` to be ALWAYS auto-deducted. Is there any "special rules", in which template arguments will go to CtrArgs?

Comment: @tower120 It *will* always be automatically deduced if possible. All function templates behave in that way.